# How to avoid black screen on call?

Tags: xiaomi, proximity-sensor

I have an Xiaomi Mi Max which for some reason stopped the proximity sensor at 0 and this means I get black screen on every call (Whatsapp calls in particular) and I cannot do anything but restart. The phone is rooted and I wish to find a way to use my phone otherwise I have to probably throw it away as the sensor itself cannot be found in my country.

Is there any trick or application which can help me disable or otherwise set the proximity sensor to a number that it doesn't bug me?

Answer (score 0):

Download and install xposed framework then download sensor disabler..
Sensor Disabler (previously known as Disable Proximity) allows you to disable and modify the values for all the sensors available in your phone, including the proximity sensor!
Simple as that!!

Hope it helps (^-^)